# translation in html file

Tags: magento2.2, localisation, translate

i have one legacy module with .html file, which contains label which i'd like to translate.
Originally it looks like this:

```
<label class="label" for="carrier_department"><span>text to be translated</span></label>
```

i have changed it to:

```
<label class="label" for="carrier_department"><span data-bind="i18n: 'text to be translated'"></span></label>
```

but this is not helped, it's still not translated.
p.s. cache cleaned, re-deployed, translation exist in csv file.
any ideas?

Comment: cache did the trick, as usual((((

Answer (score 2):

The below code works for me

```
<h4 data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping Instruction'"></h4>
```

Hope it will work for you. In your case it should be

```
<label class="label" for="carrier_department"><span data-bind="i18n: 'text to be translated'"></span></label>
```

For more details, please have a look the below link:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html