# Magento 2: How to translate knockout html file for word that contains hyperlink?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, html, inline-translations, i18n

I have a text like this:

```
To contact us please email us at joe@mail.com, will be waiting!
```

when the user clicked on the email it will redirect the user to mail link, using phtml i can easily achieve it like this:

```
<p>
 <?= __("To contact us please email us at %1, will be waiting!",'<a href="joe@mail.com">joe@mail.com</a>') ?>
</p>
```

but i have trouble on putting this in knockout HTML file, because i don't know if it can support like that, it needs to be translated with this format:

```
XXXXXXXXX ZZZZZZ VVVVV joe@mail.com
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the html binding:

```
<p data-bind="html: textlink"></p>
```

Whatever exists in 'texlink' (can be a variable or string) would come translated.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the below link to translate the word in html file

[translation in html file](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/224814/translation-in-html-file)